# Bash Script on a Mac creates a info popup

Tags: macos, bash

Is there a way in bash on a mac to draw a pretty info box that displays a simple message like "please save all files to /Users/......"

Comment: My first thought was AppleScript, but I have a feeling it may not be possible to do it that way. This command: `osascript -e "display dialog \"hello\""` gives the error "No user interaction allowed". See http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-studio/2002/May/msg00099.html

Comment: Yeah, you're right - the key is to tell "System Events" to display the dialog for you ;)

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure that knowledge will come in useful one day.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can run fragments of applescript from you bash scripts.
A simple popup would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/osascript <<-EOF

    tell application "System Events"
        activate
        display dialog "Hello world"
    end tell

EOF
```

This will feed the applescript between the EOF tags to osascript and execute it
(resulting in a Hello World popup).

Comment: `osascript` was made a UI element process in 10.9, so you can now use just `osascript -e 'display dialog ""'` instead of `osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog ""'`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to osascript "System Events" would be to install [cocoaDialog](http://mstratman.github.com/cocoadialog/).

cocoaDialog has the disadvantage that it must be installed, but it seems to be much more flexible than the "System Events".

The license is GPL, so you can freely redistribute it, since it is a separate application.

(osascript was littering my terminal with error messages (at least under Lion) and with return values, it didn't let me do popups with timeouts, and seemed to require specific quoting which made it hard to use variables in the texts.)